# How to get all input-fields with same name-tag as array (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

Is it possible to get all input-fields with the same name-tag as array and use the string in square bracket as key?
Example:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[idPub]" disabled="disabled">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[idPri]" disabled="disabled">  
<textarea name="hidden[description]" style="height:75px;length:auto;display:block;" class="form-control" >'</textarea>
```

The result should be like that:

```
hidden => 
    "idPub" => 123,
    "idPri" => 321,
    "description" => 'test'
```

My actual solution:

```
var formData = [];
        $("input[name^='hidden[']").each(function()
        {
            formData[$(this).attr('name').replace('hidden[','').replace(']', '')] = $(this).val();
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is 123 and 321 and 'test' in your html? you can select elements that start with an attribute, like `input[name^="hidden"]` selects all inputs which names start with hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using named keys, `formData` should be an **object**, not an array.

```
var formData = {};
//             ^^
```

Additionally, your selector is only targeting `<input>` elements; you'll want to add a selector for `<textarea>` as well.

```
$("input[name^='hidden['],textarea[name^='hidden[']")
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var formData = {};
$("input[name^='hidden['],textarea[name^='hidden[']").each(function() {
  formData[$(this).attr('name').replace('hidden[', '').replace(']', '')] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(formData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[idPub]" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden[idPri]" value="321">
<textarea name="hidden[description]">test</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const formData = {};

const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden]"));

elements.forEach(el => {
    const key = el.getAttribute('name');
    var matches = key.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);

  if (matches) {
    var val = matches[1];
    formData[val] = el.value;
  }
});

console.log(formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using regex as well.

```
var hidden = {};
$('input,textarea').filter(function(){
  return this.name.match(/(hidden)\[(.*?)\]/g);
}).each(function() {
  hidden[$(this).attr('name').replace('hidden[', '').replace(']', '')] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(hidden);
```

Check it out here: [How to get all input-fields with same name-tag as array (jQuery)](https://codepen.io/gauravjha8298/pen/XLzVJe)